# Understanding data type of pandas series

Tags: pandas, series

I have a Pandas series sliced from a DF. The series has about 100000 rows where some of the values are Float type and the others are infinity. But python specifies the whole series as an 'Object' type. So when I try to remove non-numeric value, the whole series becomes NaN.

Below is an example of the how the table is structured and all types of non-numeric enteries. °° This symbol specifies inifinity.

| Time (µs) | ChannelA (mV) | ChannelB (mV) | ChannelC (mV) | ChannelD (mV) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.11 |
| 4 | 0.8 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.6 |
| 5 | °° | °° | °° | °° |

Why does python specify the whole series as an Object ?

Comment: can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (sample data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each columns to numeric using `pd.to_numeric`, and passing `errors` as `coerce` which will convert non-numeric string values to `NaN`.

```py
for c in df:
    df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
df
   Time (µs)  ChannelA (mV)  ChannelB (mV)  ChannelC (mV)  ChannelD (mV)
0          1            0.1            0.2            0.3           0.40
1          2            0.5            0.7            0.4           0.50
2          3            0.6            0.2            0.3           0.11
3          4            0.8            0.6            0.7           0.60
4          5            NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
```

Data types after conversion:

```py
>>> df.dtypes:
Time (µs)          int64
ChannelA (mV)    float64
ChannelB (mV)    float64
ChannelC (mV)    float64
ChannelD (mV)    float64
dtype: object
```

You can also replace those `°°` characters by `inf` which represents infinite value if you don't want to use `NaN`, using `replace`, then you can convert the dataframe to `float`.

```py
df.replace('°°', float('inf')).astype(float)

   Time (µs)  ChannelA (mV)  ChannelB (mV)  ChannelC (mV)  ChannelD (mV)
0        1.0            0.1            0.2            0.3           0.40
1        2.0            0.5            0.7            0.4           0.50
2        3.0            0.6            0.2            0.3           0.11
3        4.0            0.8            0.6            0.7           0.60
4        5.0            inf            inf            inf            inf
```

Comment: This worked. But why was previously the whole column of Channel A was shown as an 'Object' data type?

Comment: For the column with numeric/non-numeric values, pandas always store them as object dtype.